# Tranfer Data from Datagrid to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridview and it has its data source as a Data-table. Now I have added another DataGridViewTextBoxColumn in the datagridview where user can enter details. So now the source Data-table doesn't contain this column but the datagridview has .

I need to have the entire datagridview columns in a Data-table(either the source Data-table or else a new Data-table). Is it possible ?  Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have this question tagged with asp.net, however DataGridView is a Winforms control....

Comment: @BFree ..Changed it to Winforms..Thanks

Comment: how do you want to update the information once the user entered the data?

Comment: @Roopesh..I'll do that..Answers to few questions @Documentum CMS , AdobeFDK were not acceptable.

Comment: @Mor. Well , GridView columns will be updated when user enters some data into one particular column (as the value in next column is derived from what user has entered) and also with a status of a radio button .( one column will be disabled based on the radio button status)

Comment: How are you filling and defining the datatable?

Comment: I have set the DataSource of the GridView to a datatable. Hence the GridView will display the columns int the datatable. But I have also added another DataGridViewTextBoxColumn where user enters some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you modify the DataTable before you bind it to the DataGridView? You should be able to add a new column to the DataTable, set it to editable then bind to the DataGridView. Now updates to the DataGridView will be transfered back to the DataTable.